# Using vee-validate for validation of dropbox

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vee-validate

Sorry for the very basic question

I'm trying to validate a form using vee-validate. text/email/number fields are not a problem. But I couldn't find a good documentation on validating dropdown/checkbox/radio fields.

What I want is "you have to select some option from the dropdown". For that i tried

```
<p class="help is-danger" v-show="standard===''">Select the standard student is studing in.</p>
```

where standard is the property which is binded with the help of v-model="standard". This is working as intended, but i want this message to be shown when dropdown is "touched". I'm not able to figure this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround for this,

```
<div class="select" :class="{'is-success': standard!='', 'is-danger': standard=='' && standardIsFocused}">
   <select v-model="standard" @focus.once="standardToggle()">
      ...
   </select>
 </div>
 <p class="help has-text-left is-danger" v-show="standard==='' && standardIsFocused">Selecting one of the option is required.</p>
```

in script tags

```
data () {
  return {
    standardIsFocused: false,
  },
methods: {
  standardToggle() {
    this.standardIsFocused = !this.standardIsFocused
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `data-vv-validate-on` attribute:

```
data-vv-validate-on="focus"
```

Then whenever the dropdown is opened the validator will fire, for instance.

Comment: Thank you for replying, I tried to do this     <select v-model="standard" data-vv-validate-on="focus" :class="{'is-danger': standard===''}">    but it gave me no result. I also added v-validate="'required'" and binded class "is-danger" with name="standard" still no result.

Comment: So, I found around, but i'm afraid it is little to verbose. <select v-model="standard" @focus.once="standardToggle()"> and <p class="help has-text-left is-danger" v-show="standard==='' && standardIsFocused"> where standardIsFocused is set to False in data object and standardToggle() is used to toggle that property. It is little too dirty but working. Should I add an answer for this? Thank you for your input BTW.